# How do I select all shared columns within nested df in R using tidyverse functions?

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I've come up with a reprex below.  I've created a nested `df`.  The `cols` column represents columns within the nested `df`.  I am using the `cols` column to pass to the made up function using `map`.

In this case, that would be the `lifeExp` column.

How do I pass along a `select` that looks at the `cols` column and `selects` the character vector column name that exists within that row, and then `select` that row in the `sd_col` nested df?  In addition, I'd like to pass the `country`, `continent` and `sd` columns in that same `select`.  So in this case, we would be selecting, `country`, `continent`, `lifeExp`, and `sd` within the nested `df` in the `sd_col`.

I'm guessing that this could be achieved using `purrr`.

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

data <- gapminder_unfiltered


sample_fn1 <- function(data, cols){
  testdata <- data %>% 
    mutate(across(!!cols, mean))
}


sample_fn2 <- function(data, cols){
  testdata <- data %>% 
    mutate(sd = sd(pop))
}
```

```
nested_data <- data %>% 
  filter(country %in% c("United States", "Mexico", "Canada", "Argentina", "Brazil", "Italy", "Japan")) %>% 
  mutate(
    country_group = case_when(
    country %in% c("United States", "Mexico", "Canada") ~ "North America",
    country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil") ~ "South America",
    country %in% c("Italy", "Japan") ~ "Eurasia"
  )
  ) %>% 
  group_by(country_group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  ungroup()


> nested_data 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  country_group data                  
  <chr>         <list>                
1 South America <tibble[,6] [24 x 6]> 
2 North America <tibble[,6] [127 x 6]>
3 Eurasia       <tibble[,6] [114 x 6]>
```

Next

## cols to use

```
col_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~country_group, ~cols,
  "North America", c("lifeExp", "pop"),
  "South America", c("lifeExp", "gdpPercap"),
  "Eurasia"       , c("lifeExp", "pop")
)

> col_tbl
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  country_group cols     
  <chr>         <list>   
1 North America <chr [2]>
2 South America <chr [2]>
3 Eurasia       <chr [2]>
```

## join cols to use to df

```
nested_data <- nested_data %>% 
  left_join(col_tbl)
#> Joining, by = "country_group"

> nested_data
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  country_group data                   cols     
  <chr>         <list>                 <list>   
1 South America <tibble[,6] [24 x 6]>  <chr [2]>
2 North America <tibble[,6] [127 x 6]> <chr [2]>
3 Eurasia       <tibble[,6] [114 x 6]> <chr [2]>
```

## run 2 functions

```
nested_data <- nested_data %>% 
  mutate(nest1 = map2(data, cols, sample_fn1),
         nest2 = map(data, sample_fn2),
         # select specified columns 
         nest1 = map(nest1, ~select(.x, c(country, year, continent)))
         )

> nested_data
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  country_group data                   cols      nest1                  nest2                 
  <chr>         <list>                 <list>    <list>                 <list>                
1 South America <tibble[,6] [24 x 6]>  <chr [2]> <tibble[,3] [24 x 3]>  <tibble[,7] [24 x 7]> 
2 North America <tibble[,6] [127 x 6]> <chr [2]> <tibble[,3] [127 x 3]> <tibble[,7] [127 x 7]>
3 Eurasia       <tibble[,6] [114 x 6]> <chr [2]> <tibble[,3] [114 x 3]> <tibble[,7] [114 x 7]>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more of your expectation directly (i.e. keeping apart your used strategy).

Answer (score 0):

```
mutate(nested_data, answer = imap(data, ~select(.x, all_of(cols[[.y]]))))
```